# How to Store a Temporary Unmodified Model in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to store a temporary version of my `Company` model within WPF MVVM however I am having issues where even though the temp I create isn't bound to my UI elements, it is still being updated.

Here is what happens when the `ModifyCompanyViewModel` is instantiated:

```
public ModifyCompanyViewModel(Company passedCompany)
{
    SelectedCompany = passedCompany;
    _tempCompany = passedCompany;
    CloseWindowCommand = new CloseableCommand<Window>(CloseWindow);
}
```

So I have a readonly `Company` named `_tempCompany`. The UI elements are bound like so:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NameTextBox" Text="{Binding SelectedCompany.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Clearly they're bound to the `SelectedCompany`. If I then type something different in the `TextBox` that contains the Company's Name, but return the `_tempCompany` the `_tempCompany`'s name reflects that which I have typed.

How can I store the `_tempCompany` in a way that no matter what is typed it's name stays the same? I have started using this approach which works:

```
_tempCompany = new Company
{
    Id = passedCompany.Id,
    Name = passedCompany.Name
    //Other properties..
};
```

But this seems very cumbersome and that I am overlooking an easier way.

Comment: review C# refrence types to understand why _tempCompany reflects changes in SelectedCompany

Comment: Implement `ICloneable` in your model and use `_tempCompany = passedCompany.Clone()`

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for both your time. I'll look into that ASh. How can I implement `ICloneable` when the model is generated by EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectedCompany` property and the `_tempCompany` field reference the same `Company` object. If you want to store "a temporary version" of the `Company` object you need to create a temporary version, i.e. you need to create another instance of the `Company` class like you are currently doing:

```
_tempCompany = new Company
{
    Id = passedCompany.Id,
    Name = passedCompany.Name
    //Other properties..
};
```

This is not cumbersome.

As suggested in the comments you could implement the `ICloneable` interface but this just moves the creation of the other instance to a method within the class that implements the interface. You still need to create another instance somewhere.

> How can I implement `ICloneable` when the model is generated by EF?

Create a partial class and implement the `Clone` method in this one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a viewmodel. Currently `Company` is a model. Attempting to use it as viewmodel (to bind to its properties) sooner or later will cause you problem, since you mention it's generated.

Consider a simple viewmodel wrapping Company:

```
public class CompanyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly Company _company;
    public CompanyViewModel(Company company)
    {
        _company = company;
    }

    // now expose something
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _company.Address }
        set
        {
            // tracking changes
            // note: you aren't tracking changes made to model instance!
            _company.Address = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // and here is what you actually want, read-only name
    public string Name => _company.Name;

    // you can optinally expose model and bind to it properties
    // but that wouldn't let you track the changes
    // unless model implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    public Company Company => _company;

    ...
}
```

If you want to edit company name, then just make another property (call it `NewName`), set its initial value in constructor and decide for yourself when its value will replace `_company.Name` (e.g. in some method `AcceptChanges()` which will be called when user finish editing). You will be able to access both: `NewName` and not yet changed `_company.Name` to compare them and display confirmation button.